# Use LSUIElement (aka no Dock icon) but retain the "File, Edit, View" menubar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want my app to have:

- Menubar extra icon (by the clock)
- App Menubar ("File, Edit, View, Etc")

I **do not** want my app to have:

- Dock Icon

Is this possible? I am deploying for 10.6 and 10.7 via the Mac App Store if that matters.

Setting LSUIElement in the info.plist file removes the dock icon, but it also removes the menubar.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want this combination? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NSApplication's setActivationPolicy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/setActivationPolicy%3a) might be what you are after.

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

Please note the discussion:

> Currently, NSApplicationActivationPolicyNone and
>   NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory may be changed to
>   NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular, but other modifications are not
>   supported.Needs links to running application

As per [NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory) you may need to programmatically ensure that the menu bar appears.

Comment: Hmm, so that means I could start it as a menubar-icon-only app, then change it to a app that has all 3 (dock/menubar/menubar-icon). But then not change it back to only having the menubar icon. Not quite what I'm looking for but it seems as if (menubar-icon/menubar/no-dock) is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two "separate" applications. One that has a dock icon and menu items,the other one has just the icon by the clock.
When you click on the icon by the clock it launches the dock application. When you close the dock application the 'background' application stays running.

If that model will work for you then that's the way to go. But I would weigh that effort against what File-Edit-View will do for you.

Comment: Interesting, but too complex for my purposes I think. And you never do end up getting the File-Edit-View menubar without a dock icon.